# My NTFS and ext4 partition mounts as read only

Tags: ntfs, ext4, fsck

After upgrading some packets (*that I don't know what*), my *ext4* partitions are mounted as read only:

```
m@mpc ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount: warning: /mnt seems to be mounted read-only.
```

My NTFS partitions are mounted as read only too and when I want to use `fsck` it says:

```
m@mpc ~ $ sudo fsck /dev/sda5 
[sudo] password for m: 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda5
```

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: ext partitions are now ok, but still problem with NTFS.

Comment: Provide some more informations, e.g. look in boot.log, `dmsg` output, ...

Comment: I really don't know anything more :(

Comment: what if you unmount and mount it again ?

Comment: No success with that :(

Comment: Try loading LiveUSB and `fsck`-ing the partition, i had to do this once, then reboot to Live, then fsck again, and it removed a RO setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output of fsck, I can see you are using the Kernel NTFS driver which is a read-only driver.

You need to install (perhaps reinstall) the FUSE NTFS driver called `NTFS 3G`. The following command should solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

After that, either reboot or unmount and remount your NTFS partition. It should be mounted as read write. If it is not the case try forcing the type of file system with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

**NOTE**: AFAIK there are no `fsck` tool for NTFS partitions on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For my ext partition I used `fsck` and for my NTFS partitions I used a tool in ntfs-3g named `ntfsfix`. Now All is done.